# Complex JSON in ADF that has me scratching my head

Tags: azure-data-factory

So, my API payload comes looking something like this

[image]

The Json looks like this, sorry for the blackouts, but I don't know any of you and it has endpoints and peoples names. :)

[image]

How do I get this into SQLDB through ADF? I've tried flattening down to individual rows and columns ect. Can't seem to get ADF in dataflow to put it together coherently.

The data is basically a Next page API with Columns and Rows for 25 records over 401 pages. :|

Any help would be great.

Tried Pivot and all the fun stuff, but it still won't transform correctly.
Code Snippet that repeats 401 times:

```
`[
  {
    "columns": [
      "Unique ID",
      "Record Organization",
      "Record Location",
      "Created At",
      "Updated At",
      "Workflow",
      "Indicator Set: Incident Status",
      "Indicator Set: Type of Incident",
      "Indicator Set: Recordable Incidents",
      "Indicator Set: Loss Work Time",
      "Indicator Set: Body Part Injured by Incident",
      "Indicator Set: Cause of Incident",
      "Indicator Set: Classification of Incident",
      "Created By",
      "Link to Record"
    ],
    "rows": [
      [
        "INC0502",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Carson",
        "04/01/2020 01:13 PM",
        "08/12/2021 05:11 PM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Randy",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/502"
      ],
      [
        "INC0506",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Carson",
        "04/01/2020 02:49 PM",
        "10/14/2021 10:48 AM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Joni",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/506"
      ],
      [
        "INC0507",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Dominguez",
        "04/01/2020 06:57 PM",
        "10/09/2021 04:14 PM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Juan",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/507"
      ],
      [
        "INC0508",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Dominguez",
        "04/01/2020 11:39 PM",
        "08/11/2021 11:13 PM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        "Dust particle",
        null,
        "Fili",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/508"
      ],
      [
        "INC0509",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Carson 3",
        "04/02/2020 12:01 AM",
        "08/12/2021 08:41 AM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Kyle",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/509"
      ],
      [
        "INC0510",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Dominguez",
        "04/02/2020 08:48 PM",
        "10/09/2021 04:14 PM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Juan",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/510"
      ],
      [
        "INC0511",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Dominguez",
        "04/02/2020 11:48 PM",
        "08/11/2021 11:13 PM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Jennifer",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/511"
      ],
      [
        "INC0512",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Sumner",
        "04/04/2020 12:21 AM",
        "08/06/2021 11:17 PM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Laura",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/512"
      ],
      [
        "INC0513",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Dominguez",
        "04/04/2020 12:51 AM",
        "08/12/2021 08:41 AM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Michael",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/513"
      ],
      [
        "INC0514",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Dominguez",
        "04/04/2020 03:38 PM",
        "08/12/2021 08:42 AM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Andy",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/514"
      ],
      [
        "INC0515",
        "International Freight Forwarding",
        "Chicago",
        "04/06/2020 04:37 PM",
        "10/09/2021 04:13 PM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Kevin",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/515"
      ],
      [
        "INC0516",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Dominguez",
        "04/07/2020 12:26 AM",
        "10/09/2021 04:13 PM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        "Push / Pulling",
        null,
        "Fili",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/516"
      ],
      [
        "INC0519",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Sumner",
        "04/07/2020 02:43 PM",
        "10/14/2021 10:48 AM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        "Injury/Illness",
        "Yes",
        null,
        "Head/Face/Eyes",
        "Struck by object",
        "Restricted Duty",
        "Michael",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/519"
      ],
      [
        "INC0520",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Sumner",
        "04/07/2020 06:39 PM",
        "01/09/2023 10:29 AM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        "Injury/Illness",
        "Yes",
        "Yes",
        "Hand/Wrist",
        "Other",
        "Loss Work Time",
        "Michael",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/520"
      ],
      [
        "INC0521",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Sumner",
        "04/07/2020 07:44 PM",
        "01/09/2023 11:47 AM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        "Injury/Illness",
        "Yes",
        "Yes",
        null,
        "Struck by PIT",
        "Loss Work Time",
        "Michael",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/521"
      ],
      [
        "INC0522",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Dominguez",
        "04/07/2020 10:29 PM",
        "10/09/2021 04:13 PM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Juan",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/522"
      ],
      [
        "INC0523",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Dominguez",
        "04/07/2020 10:47 PM",
        "10/09/2021 04:15 PM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Juan",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/523"
      ],
      [
        "INC0525",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Dominguez",
        "04/08/2020 02:34 PM",
        "08/06/2021 11:16 PM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Abel",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/525"
      ],
      [
        "INC0526",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Dominguez",
        "04/08/2020 11:31 PM",
        "08/11/2021 11:13 PM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Jennifer",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/526"
      ],
      [
        "INC0527",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Carson 3",
        "04/09/2020 03:39 AM",
        "08/12/2021 08:41 AM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Kyle",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/527"
      ],
      [
        "INC0528",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Carson 3",
        "04/09/2020 09:34 AM",
        "08/12/2021 05:08 PM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "Yes",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Michael",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/528"
      ],
      [
        "INC0529",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Carson 3",
        "04/09/2020 10:06 AM",
        "08/12/2021 05:08 PM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        "Injury/Illness",
        "Yes",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Restricted Duty",
        "Michael",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/529"
      ],
      [
        "INC0530",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Carson 3",
        "04/09/2020 10:32 AM",
        "08/12/2021 05:08 PM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "Yes",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Michael",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/530"
      ],
      [
        "INC0532",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Dominguez",
        "04/09/2020 12:51 PM",
        "10/09/2021 04:15 PM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "Yes",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Michael",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/532"
      ],
      [
        "INC0533",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Dominguez",
        "04/09/2020 01:40 PM",
        "10/09/2021 04:13 PM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "Yes",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Michael",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/533"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "columns": [
      "Unique ID",
      "Record Organization",
      "Record Location",
      "Created At",
      "Updated At",
      "Workflow",
      "Indicator Set: Incident Status",
      "Indicator Set: Type of Incident",
      "Indicator Set: Recordable Incidents",
      "Indicator Set: Loss Work Time",
      "Indicator Set: Body Part Injured by Incident",
      "Indicator Set: Cause of Incident",
      "Indicator Set: Classification of Incident",
      "Created By",
      "Link to Record"
    ],
    "rows": [
      [
        "INC0534",
        "Yusen Logistics Americas",
        "Carson",
        "04/09/2020 04:41 PM",
        "10/09/2021 04:13 PM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Esmeralda",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/534"
      ],
      [
        "INC0536",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Dominguez",
        "04/09/2020 05:47 PM",
        "10/09/2021 04:13 PM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Juan",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/536"
      ],
      [
        "INC0537",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Dominguez",
        "04/10/2020 02:07 AM",
        "08/12/2021 08:41 AM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Michael",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/537"
      ],
      [
        "INC0538",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Dominguez",
        "04/10/2020 03:37 AM",
        "10/09/2021 04:14 PM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Jennifer",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/538"
      ],
      [
        "INC0539",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Dominguez",
        "04/10/2020 01:47 PM",
        "08/12/2021 08:42 AM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Andy",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/539"
      ],
      [
        "INC0541",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Rogers",
        "04/13/2020 11:18 AM",
        "08/11/2021 11:13 PM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Theresa",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/541"
      ],
      [
        "INC0542",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Dominguez",
        "04/13/2020 11:19 AM",
        "06/03/2021 03:15 PM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Chip",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/542"
      ],
      [
        "INC0543",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Sumner",
        "04/13/2020 01:31 PM",
        "06/03/2021 03:15 PM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Steve",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/543"
      ],
      [
        "INC0544",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Dominguez",
        "04/13/2020 03:05 PM",
        "08/06/2021 11:17 PM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Joni",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/544"
      ],
      [
        "INC0545",
        "International Freight Forwarding",
        "Los Angeles",
        "04/13/2020 05:13 PM",
        "08/06/2021 11:16 PM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        "Injury/Illness",
        "Yes",
        null,
        "Back",
        "Accident involving moving motor vehicle",
        "Restricted Duty",
        "Alex",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/545"
      ],
      [
        "INC0546",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Dominguez",
        "04/13/2020 09:38 PM",
        "10/09/2021 04:13 PM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Fili",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/546"
      ],
      [
        "INC0562",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Dominguez",
        "04/13/2020 10:47 PM",
        "10/09/2021 04:13 PM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Juan",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/562"
      ],
      [
        "INC0563",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Dominguez",
        "04/14/2020 12:29 AM",
        "10/09/2021 04:14 PM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Juan",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/563"
      ],
      [
        "INC0564",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Dominguez",
        "04/14/2020 04:48 AM",
        "08/11/2021 11:13 PM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Fili",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/564"
      ],
      [
        "INC0566",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Dominguez",
        "04/14/2020 10:46 PM",
        "10/09/2021 04:13 PM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Juan",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/566"
      ],
      [
        "INC0567",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Dominguez",
        "04/15/2020 12:06 AM",
        "10/09/2021 04:15 PM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Juan",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/567"
      ],
      [
        "INC0570",
        "International Freight Forwarding",
        "Atlanta",
        "04/15/2020 01:41 PM",
        "06/03/2021 03:15 PM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Charles",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/570"
      ],
      [
        "INC0571",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Carson 3",
        "04/15/2020 10:20 PM",
        "08/12/2021 08:41 AM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Kyle",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/571"
      ],
      [
        "INC0572",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Dominguez",
        "04/15/2020 10:58 PM",
        "06/03/2021 03:15 PM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Nicholas",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/572"
      ],
      [
        "INC0573",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Dominguez",
        "04/15/2020 11:23 PM",
        "10/09/2021 04:13 PM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Juan",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/573"
      ],
      [
        "INC0575",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Waco",
        "04/16/2020 08:37 AM",
        "09/16/2021 02:41 PM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Geoffrey",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/575"
      ],
      [
        "INC0576",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Carson 3",
        "04/16/2020 10:53 AM",
        "09/15/2021 08:58 AM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Alejandro",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/576"
      ],
      [
        "INC0577",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Carson",
        "04/16/2020 11:37 AM",
        "09/15/2021 08:58 AM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Alejandro",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/577"
      ],
      [
        "INC0578",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Carson",
        "04/16/2020 12:00 PM",
        "09/15/2021 08:58 AM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Alejandro",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/578"
      ],
      [
        "INC0580",
        "Contract Logistics Group",
        "Dominguez",
        "04/16/2020 03:00 PM",
        "09/15/2021 08:58 AM",
        "Closed",
        "Closed",
        null,
        "No",
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        "Jesus  (WHSE Supervisor)",
        "https://company.us.donesafe.com/module_records/580"
      ]
    ]
  },'
```

Comment: Please paste the JSON as text, not an image.  Redact and change values as need be.

Comment: Could you please provide your sample JSON

Comment: @Skin Added code block to original

Comment: @Bhavani Added to edited post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I have taken the response as a JSON file for demonstration. Use transformations as shown in the below dataflow JSON:

```
{
    "name": "dataflow1",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "Json1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source1"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "csv1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "sink1"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumn1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "select1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumn2"
                },
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumn3"
                },
                {
                    "name": "rank1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "select2"
                },
                {
                    "name": "union1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "sort1"
                }
            ],
            "scriptLines": [
                "source(output(",
                "          columns as string[],",
                "          rows as string[][]",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false,",
                "     documentForm: 'documentPerLine') ~> source1",
                "source1 derive(rows = unfold(rows)) ~> derivedColumn1",
                "source1 select(mapColumn(",
                "          columns",
                "     ),",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> select1",
                "derivedColumn1 derive(rows = replace(replace(toString(rows),'[',''),']','')) ~> derivedColumn2",
                "select1 derive(id = 0,",
                "          columns = replace(replace(toString(columns),'[',''),']','')) ~> derivedColumn3",
                "derivedColumn2 rank(asc(rows, true),",
                "     output(id as long),",
                "     dense: true) ~> rank1",
                "rank1 select(mapColumn(",
                "          rows,",
                "          id",
                "     ),",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> select2",
                "select2, derivedColumn3 union(byName: false)~> union1",
                "union1 sort(asc(id, true)) ~> sort1",
                "sort1 sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     partitionFileNames:['output.csv'],",
                "     umask: 0022,",
                "     preCommands: [],",
                "     postCommands: [],",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true,",
                "     mapColumn(",
                "          rows",
                "     ),",
                "     partitionBy('hash', 1)) ~> sink1"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

- I am writing the above data to a csv file using the following dataset configurations:

[image]

- Now, this generates the file as shown below. Read this file with first row as header to get the data in required format.

[image]

Comment: Sai, this worked with some tweaks! Had to add an aggregate and additional select column, but it got me there!